# LayoutView внутри другого LayoutView?

Tags: view, коллекции, marionette.js

В браузере отрисовывается форма Marionette.LayoutView, которая содержит коллекцию Marionette.CollectionView из пяти моделей. Код шаблона:

```
<script type="text/html" id="main-layoutview">
    <div class="collection_content"></div>
</script>
```

Код представления:

```
var View = Mn.LayoutView.extend({
    template: $(html).filter('#main-layoutview')[0].outerHTML,
    regions: {
        collectioncontent: '.collection_content'
    },
    onRender: function() {
        this.getRegion('collectioncontent').show(this.collectionview);
    }
}
```

Сейчас мне нужно дублировать эту коллекцию на другую форму с другим стилем и другими элементами вокруг. Вызываться новая форма может только из первой. Я делаю новый html-шаблон:

```
<script type="text/html" id="legend-form">
    <div class="leg_content"></div>
</script>
```

и добавляю во View функцию

```
openLegend: function(collectionView) {
    var LegendLayout = Mn.LayoutView.extend({
        template: $(legend_html).filter('#legend-form')[0].innerHTML,
        regions: {
            'legendcontent': '.leg_content',
        },
    });
    var colview2 = new Marionette.CollectionView({
        collection: collectionView.collection,
        childView: ItemView
    });
    var Legends = new LegendLayout();
    Legends.render();
    Legends.showChildView('legendcontent', colview2);
    return Legends;
},
```

на что клиентская часть на строчке `Legends.showChildView('legendcontent', colview2);` ругается:

```
message:"An "el" .leg_content must exist in DOM"
```

То есть нельзя создавать вью внутри другого вью? Я не могу найти этого в документации. И как мне тогда поступить, если обе коллекции должны быть связаны, то есть при изменении в одной коллекции нужно менять вторую?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы продублировать данные коллекции в другую форму, не нужно создавать новый темплейт. Нужно добавить в существующий шаблон новый `<div>`, обернув его в тег `<form></form>`.

```
<script type="text/html" id="main_layoutview">
    .... существующий темплейт
    <form class="leg_form" style="display:none;...">
        <div class="leg_content"></div>
    </form>
</script>
```

И добавить в существующий `LayoutView` новый регион:

```
var View = Mn.LayoutView.extend({
    template: $(html).filter('#main_layoutview')[0].outerHTML,
    regions: {
        legendcontent: '.legend_content', // существующий регион
        legend2content: '.leg_content'    // новый регион
    },
    ....
    openLegend: function(collectionView) {
        this.ui.leg_form.css('display','inline');
        var colview = new Mn.CollectionView({
            emptyView: collectionView.emptyVview, 
            collection: collectionView.collection,
            childView: LegendItem
        });
        this.legend2content.show(colview);
    },
```

Теперь при необходимости можно отобразить новый вью в регионе, и он будет отображён на другой форме соответственно настроенным в шаблоне стилям.